# Fix Margin-left Position on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to fix my margin-left value on resize.
I try to write a horizontal slider.

this is my html markup. Section floats left and article got the width of all sections.... the #mainSlider has a variable Width.

```
        <div id="mainSlider" class="c12" >
            <article class="slides">
                <section>1</section>
                <section>2</section>
                <section>3</section>
                <section>4</section>
            </article>
        </div>
```

and this is the test snippet who should worke but it does not;) WHY?

```
th3width = function(){
wd = $('#mainSlider').innerWidth();
$('article').css({'margin-left' : - wd +"px" });    
}
th3width();

$(window).resize(function(){
th3width();
});
```

Comment: In the css function shouldn't it be 'margin-left:' not 'margin-left'. I am a bit rusty in CSS, HTML, and Javascript so that may not even be the answer.

Comment: Can you post the CSS for elements concerned?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does `wd` have a usable value? Probably doesn't matter, but don't mix single and double quotes within your CSS string. Also, the `-` before the `wd` might not be doing what you think it should...maybe try putting that in a string as well.

Comment: Yes wd have a valid value whene I scale and reload everything is fine. but when i resize the browser my margin left acts strange. when my  #mainSlider has a width of 500px my margin left of article could be maybe 1000 if i resize my #mainSlider to 425px for example i would like to get an margin left of 850px. the left corner from my section should be the same as the left of my # mainSlide. if section 1 (margin-left 0) is there, it works fine but if section 2 (margin-left -1time the width #mainSlide) it breakes..... Sorry, its complicated for me to explain;)

Answer (score 0):

use **marginLeft** not **'margin-left'**? http://jsfiddle.net/snsuu27x/

```
.css({marginLeft : wd+'px'})
```

Comment: nope this dosnt worke because my #mainSlider has a variable width and i would like to position my section n-times left of the changed width. For example my section is on margin-left -2xmainSlider-Width, now it should stay at this position on resize/scale my #mainSlider